# Is there a way to group Runnable Tasks into the same thread based on a property so that Runnables with the same property run synchronously?

Tags: java, multithreading

Lets say I have an `ExecutorService`, which I use to run `Job` objects, a class which extends `Runnable`.  I want my `Job` objects to run in parallel, except that it can be detrimental to have 2 `Job` objects with the same `job.getTypeId()` running at the same time. So if I am going to `submit` a job, I have to first make sure that there isn't already one with the same `job.getTypeId()` running, and if there is, it needs to be queued behind it untill it is done.

This is an edge case: Job's with the same TypeId are generally not submitted around the same time, but if they do, i need to be able to handle it properly.  While it is an edge case, it is an important use case.

The best Idea I have come up with would be to have some sort of `Collection` of `ExecutorServices` that have been configured similarly to `Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor`, like a `HashMap` where my `TypeId` would be a key associated with a Single Threaded Executor.  Maintaining this, while entirely possible feels like it would be much more of a hassle than an alternate solution.  The thing is, it might be possible to get several `jobs` that needs to be run synchronously, but then never see that `TypeId` again. I would need to implement a method of cleaning out any Single Threaded Executors that hadn't been used in a while in order to avoid a memory leak from my growling list of Single Threaded Executors.

I just wonder if I'm trying to solve a problem that has already been solved.

Is there already an execution model that solves my problem?  Is there a way to configure a threadpool to, for instance, create a Thread with my `Job.getTypeId()` in its thread name, and upon submission, assign all `Job` Objects with the same `TypeId` to the same thread?

Comment: So two jobs with the same type id can be executed in different threads as long as they are not executed in parallel? Is there a fixed set of possible type ids or can there be arbitrarily many of them?

Comment: That is correct, it isn't required that they be in the same thread, just that they not be running at the same time. and no, unfortunately there is not a fixes set of possible id's.  The TypeId actually represents the client (company) that the job is being run for, and clients come and go, as do their unique id's.  we can run many jobs in parallel, as long as no more than 1 job per client is running at a time.

Comment: @JHixson newSingleThreadExecutor seems to address the wrong problem. One normal executor service is enough. It seem to me that what you need is a `HashMap<JobTypeId, SpecialSynchQueue>`, where the `SpecialSynchQueue` is a queue that holds jobs of same type, enqueues new jobs of this type, and submits the next job whenever the previous job of this type finishes execution. For this, you would have to wrap each job into another class that pokes the queue as soon as the job is finished, so that the queue wakes up and eventually submits next job of same type to executor. Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Collegue of Mine pointed me to a great solution, someone can feel free to give additional solutions that they feel are better.  The Solution was to utilize Striped Locks from Guava to allow thread to Lock a particular JobTypeId.  This means that two thread can be created for the same JobTypeId, but the one that is created first will lock that Id, and the other will be blocked from running until the lock becomes available again.  The jobs with the same TypeId aren't running on the same *thread*, but they are all running on the same *stripe*

Striped Documentation: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html

Lock Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html?is-external=true

Code:

```
public class JobRunner implements Runner {

    private final Striped<Lock> locks;
    private final int typeId;

    public JobRunner(Striped<Lock> locks, int typeId){
        this.locks = locks;
        this.typeId = typeId;
    }

    public void run() {
        lock = locks.get(typeId);
        lock.lock() //This blocks the thread untill the lock becomes available if it wasn't already
        doWork()
    }

    private void doWork(){
        //Bus, do your stuff!
    }

}
```

As long as all JobRunners are sharing the same `Striped<Lock>` singleton, everything should work great.